# OpenCL C++ context properties syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, opencl

I'm trying to learn OpenCL using the C++ bindings. The only thing I haven't understood so far is the following syntax. Trying to create a context based on a device type:

```
cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, properties);
```

I'm using nvidia's ICD, which as I understand won't let you create a context without defining the platform, so I need the second argument. From the standard, `cl_context_properties` should be a list of property names, followed by the corresponding values, ended by 0. There's only one `cl_context_properties` in the standard (table 4.4), which is the property `CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM` and has property value of `cl_platform_id` type. Based on that I thought therefore that this should be OK:

```
cl_context_properties properties[] = 
    { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platforms[0], 0};
```

where `platforms` is my vector of platforms. But it will fail to compile unless instead of `platforms[0]` I put:

```
(cl_context_properties)(platforms[0])()
```

This is from the example code in the `cl.hpp` header file.

1) It looks like `platforms` is being cast to type `cl_context_properties`. Why is this necessary?

2) Why is there an extra set of brackets `()` at the end?

Please assume that I'm not a C++ expert (definitely true). I know it's only a small thing but I don't like writing code that I don't understand fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not any experience related to OpenCL. 
So mainly my answer is about C++ using.

1. **Why cast is necessary?**
   The cast is necessary, because you're declaring C array `properties[]` where each element should be of type `cl_context_properties`.
   Since cl_platform_id has different type it should be cast to appropriate type, exactly - `cl_context_properties`.
   You're using C-style cast that looks like this:
   (type_to_cast_to)(expression_to_be_cast).
   If `expression_to_be_cast` is just a variable like in you case you can omit parentheses around `expression_to_be_cast`:

   cl_context_properties properties[] =
        { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)platforms[0], 0};
2. **Why is there an extra set of brackets () at the end?**
   You should use the brackets since variable `platform[0]` is of type `cl::Platform` which is not plain type (like int, char, double for example) and `cl::Platform` class is a wrapper. You should invoke operator() of this class in order to get underlying data of type `cl_platform_id` that you need.
   So next code should be simpler:
   `cl_context_properties properties[] =
        { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, static_cast<cl_context_properties>(platforms[0]()), 0};`

Here you're doing cast with C++ style cast `static_cast` which is preferable cast in C++ ( [you can read about it here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) ) of object returned by invocation of `operator()` on object `platforms[0]`.
The `operator()` is defined in class `cl::detail::Wrapper< T >` ([class reference](http://kosobucki.pl/cl_doc/classcl_1_1detail_1_1Wrapper.html)) which is parent class for class `cl::Platform`

Comment: 1) OK, I think I understand the need to cast now - I guess you can't have an array which contains different types, after all.

2) If I compile without the extra brackets you get: `error: invalid cast from type ‘cl::Platform’ to type ‘cl_context_properties {aka long int}’`

Comment: The parenthesis on the C++ wrapper are to get the native OpenCL object. The operator() is defined to do that. I'd think it might be "(cl_context_properties)(platforms[0]())" though (take the first cl::Platform from the vector, get the OpenCL handle, cast it to cl_context_properties to put it in the array).

Comment: @Dithermaster, thanks! Both `(platforms[0]())` and `(platforms[0])()` work though

Comment: @FedorNesterenko, in your part 2) answer the type to cast to should be `cl_context_properties`, not `cl_platform_id`? And also `static_cast` gives errors at compile. Only `reinterpret_cast` works (which is essentially a C style cast anyway I think)

Comment: @JohnnyLyco, yes, you're right there should be cl_context_properties type in cast.